# Android: Send a Real Time Event from Activity To Fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I know that when I want to send a real time event from fragment to activity I use `setFragmentResult()` and it works fine, now I want to do the opposite.
I want to pass an event from the parent activity to the fragment and do some code based on that event. How do I do that?

Comment: Call a function on the fragment.

Comment: Or, have them share a Jetpack viewmodel. Have the activity call a function on the viewmodel to update it, and have the fragment observe changes published by the viewmodel (e.g., `LiveData`, Kotlin `StateFlow`).